# trying to connect to remote oracle server via cygwin

Tags: oracle, cygwin

When I use the command:

```
sqlplus username@ip_address:1521
```

I get the error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

When I set `ORACLE_HOME` to `/cygdrive/c/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1`, I get a different error:

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

I can telnet to the server's port 1521.

I also tried the Windows path for ORACLE_HOME but it gives me the same error, also in Cygwin when I change the `$PATH = $ORACLE_HOME/bin` no command is recognized.

I am able to connect to this database via a excel macro but not using cmd.exe or Cygwin .

Comment: This question doesn't belong here. Should be moved to another site, server fault, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use TNSNAMES.ORA to specify the connection parameters you need to provide them on the command line. This works with the widest variety of SQLPlus versions.

```
sqlplus OraUser/OraPassword@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=remoteServer)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=OraSid)))'
```

Note ' is for Unix and needs to be changed to " for Windows.